# PDFBox 3.0.0 OutOfMemory error when adding protection

Tags: java, pdfbox

I have a pdf that's 221MB, and all I'm trying to do is disable modification and add password protection. I'm using PDFBox 3.0.0-RC1 and Corretto 11. The red arrow in the heap usage graph is the point when `inDoc.save(outFile);` is called. When I don't call `inDoc.protect(pp);`, the file saves just fine with no error. One other thing that works is using `MemoryUsageSetting.setupTempFileOnly()`.

Why is it using so much memory?

```java
File inFile = ...
File outFile = ...

try (PDDocument inDoc = Loader.loadPDF(inFile, MemoryUsageSetting.setupMixed(75*1024*1024))) { // 75 MiB
    AccessPermission perms = new AccessPermission();
    perms.setCanModify(false);
    perms.setCanAssembleDocument(false);
    perms.setCanExtractContent(false);
    perms.setCanFillInForm(false);

    StandardProtectionPolicy pp = new StandardProtectionPolicy("password", null, perms);
    pp.setPreferAES(true);
    pp.setEncryptionKeyLength(128);

    inDoc.protect(pp);
    inDoc.save(outFile);
}
```

Stack trace:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.base/java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3745)
    at java.base/java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:120)
    at java.base/java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:95)
    at java.base/java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:156)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:102)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.io.IOUtils.toByteArray(IOUtils.java:84)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.encryption.SecurityHandler.encryptStream(SecurityHandler.java:559)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfwriter.COSWriter.visitFromStream(COSWriter.java:1391)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSStream.accept(COSStream.java:402)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfwriter.COSWriter.doWriteObject(COSWriter.java:599)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfwriter.COSWriter.doWriteBodyCompressed(COSWriter.java:485)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfwriter.COSWriter.visitFromDocument(COSWriter.java:1291)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSDocument.accept(COSDocument.java:400)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfwriter.COSWriter.write(COSWriter.java:1569)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfwriter.COSWriter.write(COSWriter.java:1456)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.save(PDDocument.java:1010)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.save(PDDocument.java:955)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.save(PDDocument.java:912)
```

`-Xmx512m`

[image: Heap usage graph]

Comment: Who needs a PDF that huge?! Also the latest version isn't RC1, it's 3.0.0-alpha3. Try other things to optimize your PDF, e.g. reuse fonts and use the best possible compression (CCITT for b/w scans), FLATE for color images with sharp edges and JPEG for photos.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr The original PDF was created elsewhere. I’m just trying to modify it. Why do I need to go through all the work of finding fonts to reuse, images to compress, etc. just to simply open and re-save a PDF? It doesn’t seem like good memory management if a 221MB file takes more than 512MB to process, especially when the ‘MemoryUsageSetting’ is set to 75MB.

Comment: Most likely the content of the PDF is compressed, see 1st comment. I usually run my applications with -Xmx2G, sometimes up to -Xmx4G.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try version 3.0.0-alpha3 and a larger max heap to see if it'll at least finish. By the way, I was under the impression that the [software release lifecycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_release_life_cycle) went alpha -> beta -> RC.

Comment: It only used about 425MB of heap with 3.0.0-alpha3 and no other changes.